# Uk bank statement visa for short term study

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am planning to come to the Uk for a short course . My father is paying everything but the only problem here is that my father doesn’t have money in his bank account . He stores his money somewhere in a safe lock . What do I do ? How do I show them that my father will support me ?

Answer (score 3):

This is virtually impossible without bank statements or some other reliable and verifiable documentation to show a) the source of your father’s support for you; and b) his ability to fulfil his commitment. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)