# Bank statement UK visa

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, proof-provenance-of-funds

I will be apply for a short term study visa but my fathers bank statement which I will be using doesn’t show any activity in the past 6 months other than a deposit of 3,000 USD which he got out of an investment. The balance is 21,000 . Is it fine if the bank account isn’t very active ?

Comment: You keep asking the same questions https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142633/uk-bank-statement-visa-for-short-term-study and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143128/is-this-considered-funds-parking-uk-visa-bank-statement

Comment: He surely has other accounts which have activity? You are limited to a single account, you can provide statements for as many accounts would be needed to show both savings and income over the period.

Comment: @jcaron I think you meant "You are NOT limited to a single account, ..."

Comment: From the other questions, it appears to be a predominantly cash operation, so there may be no bank statements that will show enough history. Maybe accounts and tax returns can do the job?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Oops indeed, NOT limited to a single account.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, **no**. What they want to see is not simply a large amount of money, they want to see *documented, legal income* balanced against *reasonable expenses*, with income in excess of expenses.

Gayot Fow explains this at length in another [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105). Your case would be his second example under "Funds Parking."